# Getting data in database is NULL using eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am just new in Laravel and trying to explore.

I am getting a problem where I am trying to get the data in my database using eloquent.

I just want to get the data just like this.

```
SELECT id,name,status 
FROM tre
WHERE id = 1
```

Here is my code in my controller:

```
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\TRE  $tRE
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(TRE $tRE)
    {
      return $tRE->load('tre_list');
    }
```

Here is my code in my Model:

```
    public function tre_list(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\TRE', 'id');

    }
```

But it is just return null.

```
{tre_list: null}
tre_list: null
```

Can anyone help me on what is my problem.

Comment: You say you are trying to get `SELECT id,name,status FROM tre WHERE id = 1` but in actual fact what you are doing is something like `SELECT * FROM tre_list WHERE tre_id = something`.  Are you sure you want everything in `tre` or did you mean you wanted everything in `tre_list` that is related to `tre` ?

Comment: Also, `return $this->belongsTo('App\TRE', 'id');` is looking for a foreign key of `id`.  Are you sure the foreign key in the table `tre_list` isn't named `tre_id`?  If so, try `return $this->belongsTo('App\TRE');`

Answer (score 0):

From your model remove this section because you don't need it:

```
public function tre_list(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TRE', 'id');
}
```

In your controller's show function just return like this:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\TRE  $tRE
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(TRE $tRE)
{
  return $tRE;
}
```

And if it returns null, then the TRE with that ID doesn't exist.